# R: Plotting 4x4 plot with for -loop and png, why getting 1x1 plot instead of 4x4?

Tags: r, plot, sweave

I can get the 4x4 plot working when I try it on command line but not with for -loop and png element in the code below. I am frustrated what the heck the problem is, I have tried to understand this now hours and cannot advance.

Just `$ R CMD Sweave paper.Rnw`, `$ pdflatex paper.tex` and `$ evince paper.pdf` after you copy the code below to paper.Rnw -file -- and you will get a 1x1 plot instead of 4x4 plot. Why?

```
$ mkdir Pictures
$ mkdir Data
$ cd Data
$ wget https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3128/harjoitustyot/Mat-2_3128_data_2.xls
$ cd ..
$ cat paper.Rnw

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
library(gdata)
f<-read.xls('./Data/Mat-2_3128_data_2.xls')


for(i in 1:ncol(f))
{
    png(paste('./Pictures/CO',i,'.png',sep =''))
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot(pacf(na.omit(f[,i])), main=paste('Pacf', i))
    plot(acf(na.omit(f[,i])), main=paste('Acf', i))
    plot(na.omit(f[,i]), main=paste('Data', i), type='l')
}
@

\subsection{Time-serie C1}
\includegraphics{./Pictures/CO1.png}
\subsection{Time-serie C2}
\includegraphics{./Pictures/CO2.png}
\subsection{Time-serie C3}
\includegraphics{./Pictures/CO3.png}
\subsection{Time-serie C4}
\includegraphics{./Pictures/CO4.png}
\subsection{Time-serie C5}
\includegraphics{./Pictures/CO5.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should your `par(mfrow=...)` be outside the loop?

Comment: @Andrie: probably not because it is supposed to create many 4x4 pictures with the same logic.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing `dev.off()` call at the end of the code block that begins by opening a png graphical device with `png(paste...`. Does fixing that make a difference?

Comment: I think you need to add a dev.off() to close your png device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions `acf` and `pacf` have an argument `plot` which defaults to `TRUE`. Thus, the plot statement is not required (otherwise you get two plots for `acf` and two plots for `pacf`). Note, I also added a `dev.off()` statement.

This should work:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(f))
{
    png(paste('./Pictures/CO',i,'.png',sep =''))
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    pacf(na.omit(f[,i]), main=paste('Pacf', i))
    acf(na.omit(f[,i]), main=paste('Acf', i))
    plot(na.omit(f[,i]), main=paste('Data', i), type='l')
    dev.off()
}
@
```